# SVG filters outside of a bounding box/clip path/shape

Tags: css, svg

I have filters working inside `<g>` elements with clip-paths.

```
    <g ref="backSphere" id="backSphere"></g>
    <g style="clip-path: url(#clip)">
        <use xlink:href="#backSphere" style="filter: url(#blur)"></use>
    </g>
```

Is there a simple way to "invert" this, so that the filters effectively apply to everything "outside" the clip path?

My current use case is a rectangle, but a more general answer would also be appreciated.

I know I can, for the most part:

- Cover the entire SVG with one filter, then try to calculate the inverses for the applied filters with another: not ideal because of calculations, probably double-filter performance hits, and it might not math out precisely.
- Create a piecemeal set of filter elements to patchwork in the coverage around the shape I want: not ideal because of individual positioning, and with either movement or more complex shapes this would be a bear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invert the clip path, not the filter.

SVG clip paths can contain multiple grafical primitives, like two rectangles. In this case,

> the silhouettes of the child elements are logically OR’d together to create a single silhouette

But if you use a single `<path>` element, the path can be composed of multiple subpaths, and what is clipped then is ruled by the [`clip-rule`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking-1/#the-clip-rule) property.

```
<clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"/>
   <rect x="30" y="30" width="40" height="40"/>
</clipPath>
```

would just clip to the first, larger rectangle. But exchanging the rects with equivalent subpaths,

```
<clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <path d="M0,0 h100 v100 h-100 z M30,30 h40 v40 h-40 z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
</clipPath>
```

clips to everything *in between* the two rectangular subpaths.

And that is your solution: Add an outer rectangle covering your complete viewport (or at least the filter region) to your clip path.

If you want to stay with grafical primitives, you can use a `<mask>` instead of a clip-path. White areas will be visible, black areas get hidden:

```
<mask id="clip">
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
   <rect x="30" y="30" width="40" height="40" fill="black"/>
</mask>
```

This has the additional benefit that you can write the large rectangle with percentage units, usefull for responsive behavior.